# Regex replacement of a partial string inside JS file

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following PHP Regex problem, which might be impossible to solve.

I need to pre-process JS files by replacing certain sub strings with function calls.

So basically turn this:

```
var s = "I'll sleep all day when I'm tired";
```

into this:

```
var s = "I'll sleep all "+getPreference()+" when I'm tired";
```

So far so good, the only problem is that I don't know which kind of quote is used as string delimiter in the original JS.

The string could also look like this:

```
var s = 'I\'ll sleep all day when I\'m tired';
```

which would result in:

```
var s = 'I\'ll sleep all "+getPreference()+" when I\'m tired';
```

which would just display my function call as part of the string when the JS is executed.

Long story short, I need a safe way to determine which string delimiter is used (" or ') and then modify the replacement string accordingly.

Any Regex geniuses here that have an idea? Help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks so much for the help so far.
I feel I haven't given enough context.

- Regex should be done in PHP (pre-processing the JS) not by a function inside the JS.
- I do not know anything, nor can I assume anything about the JS (e.g. the beginning or ending of the string), except that it is valid code.
- I know exactly what to replace, that's not the issue.

Consider this example:

```
     message = Theme.addToCartSuccess.replace("**product**", 
     item.title).replace(
     "**cart_link**", 
     "<a href=\"/cart\">\n    REPLACE_ME\n</a>")
     .replace("**continue_link**", 
     "<a\n    href=\"/collections/all\"\n>\n    
     REPLACE_ME\n</a>").replace("**checkout_link**", "<a 
     href=\"/checkout\">\n    REPLACE_ME\n</a>");
      return setTimeout(function() {
       _this.productMessages.html(message).addClass("success- 
      message").removeClass("error-message");
```

In the above example I need to replace string REPLACE_ME with getVar()

**UPDATE 2:**

I feel the only solution to tackle this is to backtrack from the replacement string and analyze the possible delimiters:

\" > delimiter must be "
\' > delimiter must be '
' or " > could be either, backtrack further till we hit a ; > last quote before the ; must be the delimiter.

Thoughts?

Thanks, 
Tom

Comment: I think the main problem is not quotation marks but where this function should be inserted.

Comment: Quick Question. Can't you just simply check the type of delimiter before the ending `;`?

Comment: That's easy, give me a few minutes, how do you know where to insert it.

Comment: Regex is not a suitable tool for manipulating JavaScript. You need to parse it and re-build it. Or just run the "pre-processing" one time on your source code with a find-and-replace, maybe...

Comment: Don't worry about where to insert the function call, that's not the issue. I strongly simplified it here, but just assume it's always the word 'day' that needs to be replaced.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I thought about that, too, but that's not so easy. Consider this: var s = 'some string to replace' + someVar;

Answer (score 0):

Use a capture group and back-reference:

```js
var line = 'var s = "I\'ll sleep all day when I\'m tired";'
new_line = line.replace(/(["'])(I.*ll sleep all ).* (when I.*m tired)\1;/, "$1$2$1 + getPreference() + $1$3$1;");
console.log(new_line);

line = "var s = 'I\\'ll sleep all day when I\\'m tired';"
new_line = line.replace(/(["'])(I.*ll sleep all ).* (when I.*m tired)\1;/, "$1$2$1 + getPreference() + $1$3$1;");
console.log(new_line);
```

In the regexp you can refer back to capture group 1 with `\1`, in the replacement you use `$1`.

Comment: A dirty, quick answer to just show that it works. Not a good idea.

Comment: This is intended to show the principle behind using capture groups. I don't really know exactly what he's trying to match in general.

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember if I have downvoted you before. But this time I did.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
function test( $string ){
    $pattern = '/^(var\s+s\s*=\s*)(\'|")(.+)(day)(.+\2\s*;)/';
    echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match){
        return $match[1].$match[2].$match[3].$match[2].'+getPreference()+'.$match[2].$match[5];
    }, $string);
    echo "\n";
}
```

I'm assuming you want to replace `day` with that function.

You can test it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ed530e2ffae613c93dd08e4b1538ced943a5ca9b)

And the test strings are these

```
test( <<<STR
var s = "I'll sleep all day when I'm tired";
STR
);

test( <<<STR
var s = 'I\'ll sleep all day when I\'m tired';
STR
);
```

Don't worry about the `<<<` which is a `HEREDOC` I don't really feel like explaining it, it's just a way to do strings without bothering with the quotes.

Oh and the output is this

```
var s = "I'll sleep all "+getPreference()+" when I'm tired";
var s = 'I\'ll sleep all '+getPreference()+' when I\'m tired';
```

PS. you can do it without `preg_replace_callback`, I just wanted to make it more fancy, as this just seemed boring.

```
function test( $string ){
    $pattern = '/^(var\s+s\s*=\s*)(\'|")(.+)(day)(.+\2\s*;)/';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, '\1\2\3\2'.'+getPreference()+'.'\2\5', $string);
    echo "\n";
}
```

This is Of course very specific to this answer, it will only work for `var s =` something `day` something something...   But you would have to give way more context for it to be more generic.

**UPDATE**

I changed this `(var\s+s\s+=\s+)` to this `(var\s+s\s*=\s*)` because you can have `var s="..."` with no spaces.

Cheers.